# What are the differences between gRPC AsyncIO and RabbitMQ and when to use them?

Tags: asynchronous, rabbitmq, event-handling, grpc, event-driven

I want to implement event-driven communication in my microservices architecture. For example, if event A happens, services X and Y would carry out certain things while service Z would do nothing. I am new at gRPC AsyncIO and RabbitMQ, and my research suggests that they could be both suitable for my need. What could be the pros and cons of using gRPC AsyncIO and RabbitMQ? What are the differences and when should I use them?

Comment: Take a look, please, to this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416765/which-option-is-more-suitable-for-microservice-grpc-or-message-brokers-like-rab